# kundera-cassandra set cql version on EntityManagerFactory when using spring

Tags: java, spring, cassandra, kundera

I want to use the a sequence generator in an kundera-cassandra (V3.2) entity. Referring to this https://github.com/impetus-opensource/Kundera/issues/777 I have to set the CQL Version to Version 3 when creating the `EntityManagerFactory`, and not when creating the `EntityManager`. My Problem is that I use Spring and I do not know how to set the property when autowiring the `EntityManagerFactory`.

```
@Id
@TableGenerator(name = "id_gen", allocationSize = 30, initialValue = 100)
@GeneratedValue(generator = "id_gen", strategy = GenerationType.TABLE)
private String id;
```

In my Repository i define the `EntityManagerFactory` like this:

```
@PersistenceUnit
private EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory;
```

And in my application-context.xml I define the Bean like this:

```
<bean id="entityManagerFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="cassandra_pu" />
</bean> 

<bean id="pum" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.persistenceunit.DefaultPersistenceUnitManager">
    <property name="persistenceXmlLocations">
        <list>
            <value>classpath:persistence.xml</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

So can anybody tell my where to set the version-property?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the following:

- Create an xml file say `cass-props.xml` and add the following:

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<clientProperties>
    <datastores>
        <dataStore>
            <name>cassandra</name>
            <connection>
                <properties>
                    <property name="cql.version" value="3.0.0" />
                </properties>
                <servers>
                    <server>
                        <host>
                            localhost
                        </host>
                        <port>
                            9160
                        </port>
                    </server>
                </servers>
            </connection>
        </dataStore>
    </datastores>
</clientProperties>`

- Then add the following property in your `persistence.xml`

  `<property name="kundera.client.property" value="cass-props.xml" />`

Comment: Thanks, I tried this and the following error occurs: `com.impetus.kundera.KunderaException: InvalidRequestException(why:Unknown key identifier sequence_name)`. When looking at the table `kundera_sequences` I do not see the column `sequence_name`, only `key` and `sequence_value`.

Comment: I added `pkColumnName="key"` to the `@TableGenerator(name = "id_gen", allocationSize = 30, initialValue = 100)`  and now it is working